# Python, clonar listas

Tags: python, lista, clone

Seja o código abaixo:

```
def modif1(lista):
    lista = [4,5,6]
lista = [1,2,3]
modif1(lista)
print(lista) #resultado: [1,2,3]


def modif2(lista):
    lista[0] = 4
    lista[1] = 5
    lista[2] = 6
lista = [1,2,3]
modif2(lista)
print(lista) #resultado: [4,5,6]

def modif3(lista):
    lista[:] = [4,5,6]
lista = [1,2,3]
modif3(lista)
print(lista) #resultado: [4,5,6]

def modif4(lista):
    L = lista[:]
    L = [4,5,6]
lista = [1,2,3]
modif4(lista)
print(lista) #resultado: [1,2,3]
```

A função `modif1` não muda a lista pois o scope da função já possui uma variável com o nome lista.
 A função `modif2` modifica a lista pois não possui variável de nome lista e acessa lista (no scope global).
 Na função 3 vem o inesperado: quando faço `lista[:]` não estou fazendo um clone da `lista`? Por que então ao modificar `lista[:]` eu modifico a `lista` original e não apenas o clone? Sendo isto, o que muda `modif4` de `modif3`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No Python, tudo é objeto. E parâmetros [são passados por atribuição](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) (o que mais ou menos significa que *referências a objetos* são passadas por valor). Por isso se você fizer um alteração na variável da `lista` ela não se mantém fora do escopo. Assim como no seu código, isso também ocorre nesse exemplo mais simples:

```
def teste(a, b):
    a = 10
    b = 'Hello World!'

x = 1
y = 'Bla ble bli blo blu'
teste(x, y)
print(x, y) # Imprime: 1 Bla ble bli blo blu
```

Acontece que alguns objetos são [mutáveis](http://rafs.com.br/tipos-mutaveis-e-imutaveis-em-python/), como é o caso das listas. Então quando você faz `lista[0]`, você está alterando um elemento do objeto (cuja referência você recebeu como parâmetro), e por isso essa alteração persiste. O mesmo vale para `lista[:]`. Nesse caso você está alterando vários elementos do objeto ao invés de um só. Quando você faz `lista = <qualquer coisa>`, você jogou fora o seu objeto original e criou um novo, em escopo local.

Se você quiser realmente fazer uma cópia de uma lista, use `lista.copy`:

```
def teste(lista):
    lista[0] = 99

lista = [i for i in range(10)]
teste(lista)
print(lista) # Imprime: 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

lista = [i for i in range(10)]
teste(lista.copy())
print(lista) # Imprime: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```